# Java get webpage source contains "null" at the beginning

Tags: java, web-scraping, urlconnection

For some odd reason when I try to get a webpage source using URLConnection I get a "null" in the output. Can anyone shed some light please?

My method:

```
public String getPageSource()
        throws IOException
{
    URL url = new URL( this.getUrl().contains( "http://" ) ? this.getUrl() : "http://" + this.getUrl() );
    URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8" ) );

    String source = null;
    String line;

    while ( ( line = br.readLine() ) != null )
    {
        source += line;
    }

    return source;
}
```

How I call it:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
        throws IOException
{
    WebPageUtil wpu = new WebPageUtil( "www.something.com" );

    System.out.println( wpu.getPageSource();
}
```

WPU consturctor:

```
public WebPageUtil( String url )
{
    this.url = url;
}
```

The output is always something like:

```
null<html><head>... //and then the rest of the source code, which is scraped correctly
```

Nothing difficult, right? But where is that damn "null" coming from?!

Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're initializing the `String` source will a `null` value so it's value is translated to the literal "null" on the first `String` concatenation in the `while` loop.

Use an empty `String` instead

```
String source = "";
```

or better use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Oh my god right! I feel stupid now, I've completely overlooked that! Thanks :)